# Stanford NLP: Sentence splitting without tokenization?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Can I detect sentences via the command line interface of Stanford NLP like Apache OpenNLP?
https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect

Based on the docs, Stanford NLP requires tokenization as per http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our pipeline requires that you tokenize first; we use these tokens in the sentence-splitting algorithm. If your text is pre-tokenized, you can use [`DocumentPreproccesor`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/DocumentPreprocessor.html) and request whitespace-only tokenization.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thx Jon. I was hoping we can skip tokenization for sentence detection.